# How to check whether array element matches with string using PowerShell?

Tags: powershell

Hi I want to check whether an string exist or start in set of array.

Example:

```
$str = "iit.apple"
$arr = ("apple", "mango", "grapes")

I want to check whether an array (arr) element matches or exist or starts with in string
```

I have tried using foreach loop to read each element but when matches found I am trying to break the loop.

Comment: Can you please add your attempt (using the `foreach` loop) ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the intrinsic `.Where()` method in `First` mode:

```
$str = "iit.apple"
$arr = ("apple", "mango", "grapes")

$anyMatches = $arr.Where({$str -like "*$_*"}, 'First').Count -gt 0
```

If any of the strings in `$arr` is a substring of `$str`, the `Where(..)` method will return a collection consisting of just that one element - so `Where(...).Count -gt 0` will evaluate to `$true`

Answer (score 2):

I would use regex and three "or" patterns.

```
'iit.apple' -match 'apple|mango|grapes'

True
```

Or

```
$str -match ($arr -join '|')

True
```

Or select-string takes an array of patterns:

```
$arr = "apple", "mango", "grapes"
$str | select-string $arr

iit.apple
```

Answer (score 1):

To complement [Mathias's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75187920/15339544) here is how you do it with a `foreach` loop:

```
$str = "iit.apple"
$arr = "apple", "mango", "grapes"

$result = foreach($element in $arr) {
    if($str -like "*$element*") {
        $true
        break
    }
}
[bool] $result
```

[`Enumerable.Any`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.any?view=net-7.0) can work too:

```
$delegate = [System.Func[object, bool]] {
    $str -like "*$($args[0])*"
}
[System.Linq.Enumerable]::Any($arr, $delegate)
```